# pandas: which threshold applies to each row?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a score column, e.g.,

```
scores = pd.DataFrame({"score":np.random.randn(10)})
```

and thresholds

```
thresholds = pd.DataFrame({"threshold":[0.2,0.5,0.8]},index=[7,13,33])
```

I would like to find the applicable threshold for each score, e.g.,

```
      score   threshold
 0 -1.613293   NaN
 1 -1.357980   NaN
 2  0.325720     7
 3  0.116000   NaN
 4  1.423171    33
 5  0.282557     7
 6 -1.195269   NaN
 7  0.395739     7
 8  1.072041    33
 9  0.197853   NaN
```

IOW, for each score `s` I want the threshold `t` such that

```
t = min(t: thresholds.threshold[t] < s)
```

How do I do that?

PS. based on the deleted answer:

```
pd.cut(scores.score, bins=[-np.inf]+list(thresholds.threshold)+[np.inf],
       labels=["low"]+list(thresholds.index))
```

Comment: @user3483203: the desired output is the `threshold` column in the text!

Comment: Use `pd.cut(scores['score'],thresholds['threshold'].values.tolist()+[pd.np.nan],labels=thresholds.index)`. @user3483203 had it I think.

Comment: I was just about to update with adding the `np.nan` :D

Comment: @user3483203 also copy the dataframe above, since `randn` can be anything.

Comment: @user3483203: I would accept an answer mentioning `pd.cut`

Comment: Just updated my answer using the dataframe from the question, and the update to fix the upper bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **`pd.cut`**

```
scores['threshold'] = pd.cut(
                         scores.score,
                         bins=thresholds.threshold.values.tolist() + [np.nan],
                         labels=thresholds.index.values
                      )

      score threshold
0 -1.613293       NaN
1 -1.357980       NaN
2  0.325720       7.0
3  0.116000       NaN
4  1.423171      33.0
5  0.282557       7.0
6 -1.195269       NaN
7  0.395739       7.0
8  1.072041      33.0
9  0.197853       NaN
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50991153/3483203) claims `cut` is slower than `apply` with `digitize`.  While `cut` will raise a warning here, those timings are on a very small dataframe and I believe they are misleading.  Here are some on a larger dataframe:

```
scores = pd.DataFrame({"score":np.random.randn(10)})
scores = pd.concat([scores]*10000)

%timeit pd.cut(scores.score,thresholds.threshold.values.tolist() + [np.nan],labels=thresholds.index.values)
4.41 ms ± 39.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

indeces = [None,] + thresholds.index.tolist()

%timeit scores["score"].apply(lambda x: indeces[np.digitize(x, thresholds["threshold"])])
1.64 s ± 18.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**`apply`** simply hides an explicit for-loop, while cut is vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html):

```
indeces = [None,] + thresholds.index.tolist()
scores["score"].apply(
    lambda x: indeces[np.digitize(x, thresholds["threshold"])])
```

Comment: I don't think these timings are quite fair.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) with some manipulation to get the exact result.

```
(pd.merge_asof( scores.reset_index().sort_values('score'), 
                thresholds.reset_index(), 
                left_on='score', right_on= 'threshold', suffixes = ('','_'))
     .drop('threshold',1).rename(columns={'index_':'threshold'})
     .set_index('index').sort_index())
```

and with your data, you get:

```
          score  threshold
index                     
0     -1.613293        NaN
1     -1.357980        NaN
2      0.325720        7.0
3      0.116000        NaN
4      1.423171       33.0
5      0.282557        7.0
6     -1.195269        NaN
7      0.395739        7.0
8      1.072041       33.0
9      0.197853        NaN
```